# ¿Cómo filtrar resultados de grandes cantidades de datos con un campo de búsqueda desde una base de datos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, pdo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de ERP en la web, donde estoy diseñando un buscador donde cada cliente consultará sus productos, a medida que escribe letra por letra en el input, debe filtrar los resultados y mostrarles sus productos de la base de datos de una manera lista de sugerencias, que coinciden con las cartas que escribió.
Ya diseñé el input y ya tengo las funciones para buscar los resultados obtenidos de una consulta PDO con PHP y Ajax, pero aquí es donde tengo el problema. Estoy consultando la base de datos de todos los productos con este php:

```
// Obtén todos los datos de productos al cargar la página
    elseif ($_POST['accion'] === 'cargarDatosIniciales') {
        try {
            $pagina = isset($_POST['pagina']) ? intval($_POST['pagina']) : 1;
            $porPagina = 70; // Cantidad de productos por página
            $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $porPagina;
    
            $sql = "SELECT p.id AS id, CONCAT_WS(' ', p.nombre, m.nombre) AS nombre, p.costociva, p.pv1
                    FROM productos p
                    LEFT JOIN lmarcas m ON p.empresa = m.empresa AND p.marca = m.id
                    WHERE p.empresa = :empresa_id AND p.sucursal = :sucursal_id AND p.eliminado IS NULL
                    LIMIT $inicio, $porPagina";
            
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':empresa_id', $empresaId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sucursal_id', $sucursalId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $resultados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
            echo json_encode($resultados);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

Y este Ajax:

```
function cargarDatosIniciales() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'consultas.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
          accion: 'cargarDatosIniciales',
          pagina: paginaActual,
          usuario_id: <?php echo $usuario_id; ?>,
          cliente_db: '<?php echo $cliente_db; ?>',
          cliente_usuario: '<?php echo $cliente_usuario; ?>',
          cliente_contraseña: '<?php echo $cliente_contraseña; ?>',
          cliente_ip: '<?php echo $cliente_ip; ?>',
          empresa_id: '<?php echo $empresaId; ?>',
          sucursal_id: '<?php echo $sucursalId; ?>'
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.length > 0) {
              listaDeProductos = listaDeProductos.concat(data); // Agregar nuevos productos a la lista existente
              paginaActual++; // Incrementar la página para la próxima carga
          }
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.error('Error al cargar los datos iniciales:', error);
      }
  });
}
```

Como pueden ver estoy cargando solo los primeros 70 resultados, ya que por la capacidad de memoria del navegador y la longitud de los resultados no me permite cargar más cuando carga la página.

Mi problema puntual es que algunos clientes tienen hasta 20 mil productos o más, y sé perfectamente que cargar esa cantidad de resultados en el navegador es casi imposible, entonces ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi buscador con cada letra el cliente escriba , mostrar tus sugerencias de productos, aunque fuera una cantidad tan grande? Donde o como puedo almacenar la lista de productos porque no es factible consultar la base de datos con cada letra que se escribe. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Qué tal si usas filtros predeterminados por marca o por alguna categoría? Con esto se podría reducir la cantidad de resultados?. Podrías mostrar los primeros 70 resultados y luego consultar no por cada letra sino por una palabra completa. Otra opción es usar `datatables` que te permite renderizar los resultados y filtrar en el front sin consumir recursos del back.

Comment: porque el titulo en ingles??

Comment: Cuando es una gran cantidad de registros, yo utilizo `datatables Server Side`, checa cómo funciona, así no cargarás todo de golpe ni en tus búquedas. Es una buena forma de optimizar tablas cuando son miles de registros. [DataTable ServerSide](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: @DjCrazy Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Lo que sucede es que en mi caso no aplica filtrado, ya que al empezar a escribir en el campo de búsqueda, debe mostrar los resultados que coincidan con los caracteres escritos, es en automático con cada letra que debe filtrar los resultados, no hay algún botón para buscar o algo por el estilo. Y con respecto a las datatables no sé si aplique porque según sé, se usan para paginación, pero en mi proyecto, necesito tener disponibles todos los productos, ya que si escriben alguna letra buscando algún producto, pero está hasta en una página lejana? Gracias

Comment: @Ominous Muchas gracias por tu comentario! Estuve viendo lo que me mencionaste de DataTable, pero podría servirme para lo que quiero? es decir, supongamos que un usuario empieza a escribir en el buscador y quiere buscar un producto en específico, pero no recuerda el nombre exacto, y justo el producto que desea, está en una página adelante de la que tiene cargada actualmente una cantidad de datos? cómo filtrar entre todos los productos? Muchas gracias amigo!!